# iOS autoplay not working

Tags: ios, safari, html5-video

I'm trying to autoplay a video on iOS's Safari (any version) and I'm using this HTML5 tag:

```
<video
   autoPlay="true"
   loop="true"
   muted="true"
   playsInline="true"
   poster="/assets/pictures/poster.jpg"
   src="https://myURL"
   className="stage-vid"
/>
```

For some reason it works on Chrome and on Firefox but when I check the video's `.muted` property on Chrome is set to **true** while in Safari is set to **false**. I'm using Browserstack for debugging but I tried it on an iOS device and the video is not playing even when that video doesn't even have an audio track.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to write:

```
<video muted playsinline />
```

or:

```
<video muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" />
```

?

Autoplay is possible on iOS as stated here on [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari)

There might be other cases such as Low-power mode that will block autoplay or [lower MEI](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) if it's on Chrome.

Comment: adding <video muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline" /> worked on my end.
To be noted that "muted" is also needed to make the autoplay work on Chrome.
Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, iOS blocks autoplay. The play function needs to be triggered from a click or touch event. Simulated clicks or touches does not work either. Im afraid there is nothing to do about this due to it depends on Apple.

Comment: not true - https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/. Getting it to work is another thing.

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges, at least in my tests, while on Android the Autoplay works, on iOS it does not. You have to click on the video for it to begin.